# Efficient & safe intersection of more than two sets

Tags: c++, set

Here is a C++ program which uses `std::set_intersection` twice to compute the intersection of 3 sets (then prints the result). It produces the expected result `3` but:

1. Is it safe to pass in 'newset' as both a source & destination set in the second call to set_intersection? As I understand it, with begin() and end() I'm passing references to these sets, so might I end up writing over my input by accident?
2. Is there a more efficient approach here? Should I iterate over my sets in ascending size order? Is there any advantage in rolling my own multi-set intersection as opposed to multiple calls to std::set_intersection?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> set_1 = {1,2,3}, set_2 = {2,3}, set_3 = {3}, newset;
    
    std::set_intersection(set_1.begin(), set_1.end(),
                  set_2.begin(), set_2.end(),
                  std::inserter(newset, newset.begin()));

    std::set_intersection(newset.begin(), newset.end(),
                  set_3.begin(), set_3.end(),
                  std::inserter(newset, newset.begin()));

    for(std::set<int>::iterator it = newset.begin(); it != newset.end(); it++){
        std::cout << *it;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you not simply read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection),

> [...] The resulting range cannot overlap with either of the input ranges.

so you're in undefined behavior land.

As a proof by verification of this, I can tell you that I've copied your code, compiled it, run it, and for me it prints `23`, so your correct result is just a coincidence.

Therefore, it looks like to have to rely on another temporary.

The STL doesn't seem to contain a solution for intersecting more than two sets, and you can't even use `std::set_intersection` in a nested fashion (e.g. `result = my_set_intersection(set_1, my_set_intersection(set_2,set_3))`, the reason being pretty simple: the algorithm's interface is "tainted" by iterators, i.e. it takes begin and end iterators to the sets, rather than the sets themselves as inputs; and it also returns an iterator.

Porbably Boost has something useful, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Thanks Enrico! In my real code I found, as you did, that my approach failed, so I am using a temporary set as you say. It feels inefficient to be juggling the memory around like this, but I guess it's the only option. In terms of efficiency, I think ordering the sets by size might be faster, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @JoeTodd, well, you could write your own `set_intersection` to deal with 3 sets, no? You could also consider `std::multiset`, which you could fill with the other 3 sets, and then you filter out the elements with count other than 3.

Comment: The reason that there is not an algorithm for three sets has nothing to do with iterators, tainted or otherwise. It's just that getting the intersection of two sets is much more common than getting the intersection of three sets. The standard library doesn't provide every possible variant on algorithms, just the common ones.  Changing the interface to take sets instead of pairs of iterators would have no effect whatsoever on this design decision.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I probably misworded that paragraph. I was referring to the impossiblity of doing something like `ABC = intersect(A,intersect(B,C))`. I've tried improving the wording; is it ok now?

Comment: You clearly don’t understand what iterators are designed to do. If you want to use sets in a function’s interface you can implement that on top of iterators. If you want to use iterators you can’t reasonably implement that on top of functions that take sets. Your set interface can’t directly write the  common elements to the screen without lots of otherwise useless overhead, for example.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes, I know I could do that if I want, but your comment seems to imply that nobody has interest with that type of interface, when there's a whole Range-v3 library that is based on the idea of ranges instead of pairs of iterators, so that the functions can be composed easily.

Comment: No, not at all. But “I would find this useful’ is not the same as “this should be part of the standard library”. As for ranges, yes, some folks find ranges handy, but don’t forget that one of the design goals of iterators is to allow functions to be composed easily; that’s not a new insight.

Comment: Ok, @PeteBecker, this means that don't understand is not strictly _what iterators are designed to do_, but _what is composition_. I thought composition was something like `ints | std::views::filter(even) | std::views::transform(square)` in the Example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view).

Comment: @Enlico — composition refers to using the result of a function call as an argument to another call. For example, the [remove-erase idiom](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase–remove_idiom) composes `std::remove` with `std::erase` like this: `v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 5), v.end());`

Comment: And _using the result of a function call as an argument to another call_ is exactly what happens in `ints | std::views::filter(even) | std::views::transform(square)`, which can bee seen as a `foo::transform(square, foo:filter(even, ints))`, which is similar to `my_set_intersection(set_1, my_set_intersection(set_2,set_3))` in my answer. `std::transform`, on the other hand, is not composable.

Answer (score 1):

Question1:

Not safe, as @Enrico said, it overlapped with one of the input ranges.

Question2:

You can try to refer to the idea of a classic problem: merge k sorted list using priority_queue(or called heap, or use std::set instead, because you need to find if an alement exists). The idea to the set merge problem is similar to this, and you can make complexity from O(nk) to O(nlogk), where n is the number of all elements, and there's very little transfer cost. Maybe 3 sets will be efficient because of 3 is too small to reflect the advantage of this algorithm, but when k is far more than 3, the original approach will be much slower than this one.

Note that when analyzing time complexity, though many set operations' costs are O(logn), iterate through the whole set is not O(nlogn), but O(n).